# como posso dar um "Update-Migration" no vscode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Quero usar migration do Entity Framework Core mas uso o visual studio code. Estou tentando achar uma extensão nuget no vscode que de para alterar na linha de comando(como um cmd), mas não encontro... preciso realizar alguns comandos no "console gerenciador de pacotes"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você pode fazer isso utilizando o comando no terminal:

```
dotnet ef migrations add NomeDaMigration
```

e pra atualizar:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

Comment: Não sabia, ao chegar no meu pc, vou testar.